# how to convert list of dictonaries into ....?

Tags: python, list

```
li = [[{'foo': '1',
   'date': datetime.date(2011, 2, 1),
   'bar': 'a'},
  {'foo': '2',
   'date': datetime.date(2011, 2, 1),
   'bar': 'b'}],
 [{'foo': '2',
   'date': datetime.date(2011, 1, 30),
   'bar': 'f'},
  {'foo': '5',
   'date': datetime.date(2011, 1, 30),
   'bar': 'g'}]]
```

I want to convert this list into

```
     [{'date':datetime.date(2011, 2, 1), 
       'values':[{'foo': '1', 'bar': 'a'},{'foo':'2','bar': 'b'}]}, 
      {'date':datetime.date(2011, 1, 30), 
       'values':[{'foo': '2', 'bar':'f'},{'foo': '5','bar': 'g'}]}
     ]
```

Comment: Please fix the title.  It's unhelpful to others.    You have a list of lists of dictionaries being converted into a list of dictionaries of lists.  Or perhaps, you could change it to  "help me restructure these Python objects to group by date".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
dd = []
for l in li:
    d = {'date':l[0]['date'], 'values':[]}
    for ll in l:
        d['values'].append({'foo':ll['foo'], 'bar':ll['bar']})
    dd.append(d)



print dd

[{'date': datetime.date(2011, 2, 1),
  'values': [{'bar': 'a', 'foo': '1'}, {'bar': 'b', 'foo': '2'}]},
 {'date': datetime.date(2011, 1, 30),
  'values': [{'bar': 'f', 'foo': '2'}, {'bar': 'g', 'foo': '5'}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the outer collection being a dict makes more sense:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in li:
    for y in x:
        d[y.pop('date')].append(y)

pprint(dict(d))
```

Which will produce:

```
{datetime.date(2011, 1, 30): [{'bar': 'f', 'foo': '2'},
                              {'bar': 'g', 'foo': '5'}],
 datetime.date(2011, 2, 1): [{'bar': 'a', 'foo': '1'},
                             {'bar': 'b', 'foo': '2'}]}
```

But if you want that list you can tack on:

```
L = []
for date, values in d.iteritems():
    L.append({'date':date, 'values':values})
pprint(L)
```

Which gives:

```
[{'date': datetime.date(2011, 2, 1),
  'values': [{'bar': 'a', 'foo': '1'}, {'bar': 'b', 'foo': '2'}]},
 {'date': datetime.date(2011, 1, 30),
  'values': [{'bar': 'f', 'foo': '2'}, {'bar': 'g', 'foo': '5'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another use of `pop` that reduces the size of the function:

```
>>> res = []
>>> for a_list in li:
    res_local = {'values': []}
    for d in a_list:
        res_local['date'] = d.pop('date')
        res_local['values'].append(d)
    res.append(res_local)


>>> res
[{'date': datetime.date(2011, 2, 1),
  'values': [{'foo': '1', 'bar': 'a'}, {'foo': '2', 'bar': 'b'}]},
 {'date': datetime.date(2011, 1, 30),
  'values': [{'foo': '2', 'bar': 'f'}, {'foo': '5', 'bar': 'g'}]}]
```

This solution has the advantage of being still valid if you have more items in your dicts than `foo`, `date`, `bar`, or if you remove some, etc: to sum it up, it will work if your dicts have at least a `date` entry.